# Content seperation

Tags: content-elements, content, blocks

Like most people, I have a content page that has different "blocks" of content, text blocks, pull quotes, images, gallery images, etc.,

If you're not using [content elements](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements) or the ["Blocks" plugins](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blocks) to help with content creation, what other ways outside of different fields are you using to solve the problem??

Note: Also different fields doesn't solve the problem of freedom to place content blocks where ever the author desires.

i was using CE, but a bug that can't be identified is preventing me from using it at the moment so I'm only leveraging Expresso.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link for the 'Blocks' plugin? I'd be interested in this. I too subscribe to the blocks style of page building (i.e. I want a block of X, and a block of Y, and a list of Z) but I use a modified version of [Template & Snippet Select)[https://boldminded.com/add-ons/template-select] and a template group for "dynamic blocks". I set the template selector and a 'position' style dropdown in a matrix/grid, then the editor can add a block of X, positioned 'on top', then a new grid row, block of Y ect...

Comment: There's no other way of doing it with EE without doing what you're already doing. Craft does though.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I can leverage styles in expresso/ cKeditor to help. Has anyone had luck with this approach?